# Error press button xamarin.forms using reactiveui

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I am using ReactiveUI in a Xamarin.Forms project but when I press a button I get the error: "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. '"
Here is my code.

App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new AppShell();

}
```

AppShell.xaml.cs

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Dictionary<string, Type> routes = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
        public Dictionary<string, Type> Routes { get { return routes; } }


        public AppShell()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            RegisterRoutes();
            BindingContext = this;

        }

        void RegisterRoutes()
        {
            routes.Add("monkeydetails", typeof(HomeView));

            foreach (var item in routes)
            {
                Routing.RegisterRoute(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }


        void OnNavigating(object sender, ShellNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            // Cancel any back navigation
            //if (e.Source == ShellNavigationSource.Pop)
            //{
            //    e.Cancel();
            //}
        }

        void OnNavigated(object sender, ShellNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

By default you go to the HomeView view

HomeView.xaml

```
                <Button Text="Pulsar" x:Name="Boton"></Button>
```

HomeView.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class HomeView : ReactiveContentPage<HomeViewModel>
    {
        protected CompositeDisposable ControlBindings { get; } = new CompositeDisposable();

        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> Navigate { get; private set; }

        public HomeView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
            this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.Navigate, view => view.Boton);


        }
    }
```

HomeViewModel.cs

```
 public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase, IRoutableViewModel
    {
        int prueb = 0;
        public HomeViewModel()
        {
            Navigate = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async() =>
            {

                await hola();
            });


        }
        public async Task hola()
        {

        }
        public string prueba()
        {

            return prueb.ToString();
        }

        public IObservable<string> NumberStream { get; }

        public string UrlPathSegment => "Number Stream Page";

        public IScreen HostScreen { get; }
        public override string Id => "Pass Parameter";

        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> Navigate { get; private set; }

    }
```

I can't understand why the error appears when I press the button

[image]

Comment: Looking at your code I don't see any reason for receiving this error. In Android you will get this error when you try to update the UI from another thread other than the UI Thread. When you are calling on your `ReactiveCommand` you are not doing anything inside.

Comment: pinedax. de hecho el metodo esta vacio, ya que solo estaba probando. ahora bien, lo que hice fue bajar la version a 9.x y se arreglo ,